# Saving JSON Get Responses in Django to DB? Do you fill in models and then call save?

Tags: python, json, django

Up until now, I've done most of my work through the admin panel rather than making requests for JSON data from an API. Let's say I am wanting to save this data to my database. Would the natural flow for saving to database be like this or is there a better way of doing this?

1. Make request to API and get JSON response.
   Example response: response = { 'name': bob }
2. Create Django model object with fields being set to parts of JSON. Example: Model_Ex(name=json['name'], and so on...)
3. Model_Ex.save() - makes a call to save to DB

Thanks!

Comment: While your suggested workflow is fairly standard, I'd suggest going through the official [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/) to get familiar with the way these basics are intended to be handled in the context of the framework. Also, you might want to read over [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for some useful consistency suggestions on formatting and naming (particularly when CamelCase and underscores are usually used in Python code).

Comment: If you're dealing mainly with JSON, you probably want to look at the [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).